# Openbravo rest web services

Tags: web-services, rest, openbravo

I'm starting a project that consists in OpenBravo integration via the Restful WS Layer (may be json) That kind of integration is simple in the beggining because just consists in a rest web service client which will perform the GET, PUT, POST and DELETE actions.

My question is about how to manage the json objects and if OpenBravo brings some way to convert json objects in data access objects, in order to easier handling.

I have seen OpenBravo DAL (Data Access Layer), Is there a way to mix the rest and dal to crud the OB Objects?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which might help you...
First Let us look at this code snippet

```
 public class SimpleRestClass extends BaseWebServiceServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
     String Name = request.getParameter("Name");
     String Email = request.getParameter("Email");

     List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
     Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

     map.put("Name", Name);
     map.put("Email", Email);
     // map.put("Path", request.getPathInfo().toString());

     list.add(map);
     final String json = new DataToJsonConverter().convertToJsonObjects(list).toString();

     // write to the response
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    final Writer w = response.getWriter();
    w.write(json);
    w.close();

  }

}
```

In the above code

```
final String json = new DataToJsonConverter().convertToJsonObjects(list).toString();
```

is what you are looking for. The signature of *convertToJsonObjects()* method is

```
List<JSONObject> convertToJsonObjects(List<Map<String, Object>> data)
```

The important class in openbravo for REST Json WS to notice is

```
import org.openbravo.service.json.DataToJsonConverter
```

This class has many more Json related methods. Hope this will help you.

If you have any questions then please feel free to ask.

Comment: Welcome @ Pymoo! I am happy that i was able help you.

Answer (score 2):

Openbravo has a module called **org.openbravo.service.json**

The above module makes use of JSON and DAL layer of openbravo.

When we make a get request for a product, JSON module uses DAL to query the database and convert OB Object to JSON object.

When we want to create a new product , JSON module uses DAL to create a new OB Object.

The main class you may need to focus on openbravo side is,

- 1) DefaultJsonDataService
- 2) JsonToDataConverter --Converts json data to Openbravo business object(s).
- 3) DataToJsonConverter --Is responsible for converting Openbravo business objects 
                          to a json representation.

Important link: [Openbravo JSON REST](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/JSON_REST_Web_Services)

Comment: Thank you Vel,
I'm trying to consume the web services from an standard application, how can I get these classes in my project, which jars I have to include?
What's the better way to face a project like this? 

I will be grateful if you help me.

Best Regards!

Comment: @Pymoo   You don't need any jar since your application is going to make an HTTP request and openbravo will response with json objects. In this case your standard application will be acting like a client to Openbravo JSON REST webservice.

Comment: If you want to add a business logic while creating product or sales order ,then you may need to create an extension module on top of Openbravo.

Comment: Yeah, I understand but excuse me for this newbie question: how can I access to these classes with an standard Java Application without a jar? Could you write me an example?