# connecting multiple databases(Instances) in Openbravo

Tags: postgresql, openbravo

I'm new to Openbravo development and i have a scenario where in, we have two openbravo instances lets say OB1,OB2. I need to write one DALProcess process which runs on OB1 instance and it should be able to connect to another OB2 instance and retrieve data from OB2 and insert/update data in OB1. So i need to manage two connections in my process.

I have no clue how to go ahead with this.It would be helpful if folks worked on openbravo development can share their ideas and suggestions.

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fulfill your requirement using web service. Openbravo provides webservices api that you can use to create endpoints for data exchange through restful web service on both the instances.

Say OB1 is receiver, and OB2 is the producer. So you need to create endpoint on OB2 (which basically is an URI) that will take some input parameter through GET/POST and then query DB2 and send the result in json format to OB1.

Take a look on this, it might help you regarding the Openbravo Rest API - [Openbravo Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214445/openbravo-rest-web-services/18957583#18957583)